# Are there any features on ARM64 iOS device not available if you deploy in armv7?

Tags: ios, arm64

I'd like to deploy some apps in armv7 (all our many closed source dependency libraries only support 32 bit).

I was wondering other than performance improvements, will I lose access to any specific features on arm64 devices if I do this?

Answer (score 0):

no. it is just a different arch not a different runtime version or class library

it may change in the future, but right now: no